# Comparing records in duplicate tables in different oracle databases

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the same table in two oracle databases. One is a staging database that has it's record loaded into the primary. I want to go through the staging table and see if there are no changes to the primary record. If there aren't then delete it. How can I do this?

Comment: You should add the table schemas to make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the ones where something has changed you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM "staging_table"
MINUS
SELECT * FROM "table";
```

So, assuming that the table has a primary key then you can do

```
DELETE FROM "table"
WHERE primary_key_column
      NOT IN 
      ( SELECT primary_key_column
        FROM (
          SELECT * FROM "staging_table"
          MINUS
          SELECT * FROM "table"
        )
      );
```

Comment: If you select *, the staging and production tables would have to have the same structure.  That would strike me as unusual.

Comment: If they aren't the same then you can just replace the `*`s with the shared columns.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
delete from stagingtable
where id in
(select id
from stagingtable st join productiontable pt on st.id = pt.id
and st.nextfield = pt.nextfield
etc
)
```